# Searching Google Spreadsheets with Ruby

Tags: ruby, google-sheets-api

I am trying to fetch data from a google spreadsheet in a query like format (think database) for example email=variable or something similar to the command+F you would do on google spreadsheets.

I am working with this [ruby gem](http://roo.rubyforge.org) which uses the google::spreadsheet gem for the google spreadsheet functionality.

What is the right way to search data on a google spreadsheet using these or other libraries? Before you vote this down note that *I did* read the documentation carefully and tried pretty much all possibilities I could find.

this would be equivalent to

```
  my $row = $worksheet->row({sq => 'name = "Nobuo Danjou"'});
```

from this [perl library](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aGoogle%3a%3aSpreadsheets)

which seems pretty straightforward

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: So...you're trying to find the row with a particular value? Or...? What does that Perl code do?

Comment: exactly. I like searching from a given column (e.g. email or name) a specific field. This basic but essential functionality seems missing from these above mentioned packages or any ruby gem I am familiar with ..or am I missing something ? :D

Answer (score 0):

You cannot search for rows with particular values neither with [roo](http://roo.rubyforge.org/) nor with [google-drive-ruby](https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby).
But there is such a functionality in the API: [sending_a_structured_query_for_rows](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#sending_a_structured_query_for_rows) , so that's up to a pull request.